# How to make a text appear with a desired innerHTML using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, innerhtml

There is a button and a h2 tag. the h2 tag has its visibilty=hidden.

When the button is clicked, I want to call a function that calculates the cost and changes the innerHTML of h2 accordingly and then changes its visibility=visible.

HTML:

```
<main class="form-signin">
    <form>
      <div class="card">
             <label for="inputAdult">Enter number of adults</label><input type="number" id="inputAdult" class="form-control" placeholder="No. of adults" required>
            <label for="inputChildren">Enter number of children (4-12yo)</label><input type="number" id="inputChildren" class="form-control" placeholder="No. of children" required>
           <button type="button" onclick="showCost()" id="btn3">Calculate my cost</button>
           <h2 class="changeCost">Your total cost: $0</h2>
        </div>
    </form>
  </main>
```

JavaScript / jQuery :

```
 $("h2").css("visibility","hidden");

function calculateCost(){
  var a = $("#inputAdult").val();
  var c = $("#inputchildren").val();

   if (((a+c)%3==0)||((a+c)%3==1)) {
    var rooms = (a+c)/3;
    }
   else {
    var rooms = ((a+c)/3)+1;
    }
  var cost = rooms*300;
  return cost;
}

function showCost() {
  var display = "Your total cost is: $" + calculateCost();
  var x = $("h2");
  x.value = display;
   $("h2").css("visibility","visible");
}
```

Comment: You can try to change the text in h2 tag like this:  $("h2").text("Your total cost is: $" + calculateCost());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `x.text(display)` instead of setting `value`. That changes the innerText of the element. If you'd like to set its HTML content, use `x.html(display)`.

The `value` accessor is used for plain HTMLElement objects, not for jQuery-wrapped objects.

Apart from this, you should never access a tag solely by its tag name. Always give it some kind of class name or ID. You already gave it the `changeCost` class, so you could do `$("h2.changeCost")` rather than `$("h2")`.

Comment: I tried these changes and yes! the text finally changes. but in the place it is supposed to show the calculated cost , it displays NaN

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting **NaN** do the following:
Javascript is case sensitive so replace line

```
var c = $("#inputchildren").val();
```

with

```
var c = $("#inputChildren").val();
```

I would also consider declaring rooms variable from if and else scope so it is accessible on calculations: see full function bellow:

```
function calculateCost(){
  var a = $("#inputAdult").val();
  var c = $("#inputChildren").val();
  var rooms = 0;
  
   if (((a+c)%3==0)||((a+c)%3==1)) {
      rooms = (a+c)/3;
    }
   else {
      rooms = ((a+c)/3)+1;
    }
  var cost = rooms*300;
  return cost;
}
```

Comment: Oh my God! What a silly mistake, thank you so much!